# Python Insantiate object ignoring additional Arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I frequently encounter this issue:

I have a python class defined such as:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Then I have some data with additional attributes which I would need to convert into this object.

eg `data={"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`

How can I create the object A, ignoring any additional attributes in the data with syntax such as `A(**data)` or using a generic helper method such as `toObject(A, **data)`
without including `**kwargs` in the definition of my class A.

Comment: Can you be more specific what is your expected result? Do you intend `c` to be created?

Comment: @jlandercy I want to create object `A` and ignoring any additional attributes such as `c`

Comment: Why don't you just provide the arguments directly? `A(data['a'],data['b'])`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is precisely the code I want to avoid

Comment: @user113531 then why do you define your classes to not take `**kwargs`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have to accept data created by other applications or sources. Not including `**kwargs` because it is not neccessary in the class definitions of my applicaiton. I do not want to be including `**kwargs` for the classes I am defining in my application to accommodate these data sources. It would be preferable to wrap this logic elsewhere.

Comment: ... it is not necessary, but it is *useful* for this case, no? That would be the *simple* way of making your classes accept `**kwargs` that contain arbitrary data. The only other options are hacky as heck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now using a third party library pydantic, which specifically addresses the problem of data validation and output conformation.

In this case, I want to ensure that the input data conforms to the signature of the class A. This can be achieved by the following

1. Define a Model eg. `AModel` using `BaseModel` from pydantic that matches the input parameters of the class.
2. Pass the `data` payload through the model before instantiating the class, `A(**AModel(**data).dict())` (default behavior of pydantic model ignores extra attributes)

This achieves additional validation while also being a more disciplined approach.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you will only be able to use hackey approaches. I honestly cannot think of any reason why you shouldn't be able to just provide directly the arguments you need. But Python has a lot of introspection/metaprogramming capabilities, so you can hack together something like:

```
import inspect

def instantiate(cls, payload):
    params = inspect.signature(cls).parameters
    return cls(**{k:payload[k] for k in params})

my_a = instantiate(A, data)
```

But really, this is just major code-smell to me.

You should just use `A(data['a'],data['b'])`

Comment: I was just about loading the `inspect` module.

Comment: @jlandercy yeah, the new `inspect.signature` is nice, haven't played around with it until now, really.

Comment: I totally agree

Comment: Beside you consider it as code-smell, your answer fully address the last version of the OP. Further more it is clean, short, very generic and just about 3 lines of code (thanks Python).

Answer (score 1):

If you accept to use `**kwargs`, then it is as simple as:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        # Ignore those two lines below if no need of extra args:
        if kwargs.get("update", False):
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Then `A(**data)` will ignore extra args and `A(**data, update=True)` will update the instance with extra args (including `update`).

This is just about [function signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature), the `**kwargs` ensure it will collect all extra arguments and will fit for any use or misuse, then you will never get:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
```

If you don't want to use the `**kwargs` commodity, then you should ask yourself: **Why do I accept an instance being created with wrong number of arguments and restricting the function signature at the same time?**

Summarizing, you have few options:

- Set a **fixed signature** because you intend the class to be created with this specific arguments (and why not adding a lot of `assert` in `__init__` definition), then you need to call your class instance with the correct arguments setup;
- Set a **variable signature** taking the advantage of `*args` and `**kwargs` and just not taking care of those extra arguments (if your data comes from another application in JSON format I think we may say it is safe to proceed this way);
- Create a **factory** that will preprocess arguments before instantiating, but this will add some layer of abstraction on your code that will not bring great benefit IMO;
- Another hack I haven't considered...

Recalling the Zen of Python:

```
import this
```

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Explicit is better than implicit.
- Simple is better than complex.
- Complex is better than complicated.
- Readability counts.
- Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
- There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it.
- If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
- If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.

Comment: good answer, though you may have to explain `kwargs.get("update", False)` to op

Comment: The OP explicitly stated "without including **kwargs in my definition of A"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Either I missed it or OP have been edited meanwhile I was answering